# VSCode PowerShell variables not showing in Debug panel

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Has anyone seen this? Variables not showing up when debugging. I've got a DBG prompt in the terminal and can call the active variables in the script.

Just started this morning. I don't think anything has updated. I go off and make coffee while everything starts up so may have missed something. Just started happening this morning.

The only thing I can find is a bug on Github from back in 2017 and we've moved way on from that.

I've done a full clean install of VSCode and that hasn't helped. Driving me nuts.

VSCode 1.58.1
PowerShell Extension v2021.6.2
PowerShell 5.1

[image: VSCode debug panel with no variables]

Comment: I've just done a downgrade from VSCode 1.58.1 to 1.57.1 and that didn't help. Have also downgraded the PowerShell extension to the previous version too. and that didn't help.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and stop on it, does this get populated with the locals?  That appears to be the behavior.

Comment: No nothing goes into the panel at all it's driving me nuts. I've noticed two things. If I open another Repo (also all PowerShell) it works fine. But seems no scripts work in the affected repo. Also, I noticed in the affected repo the Continue button (F5) is actually a Pause button. It's like the code is running still.

Comment: Scrap the last it's happening in both repos now which is better means it a VSCode issue.

Comment: I'm currently running VSCode 1.58.1  and the PWSH extension v2021.6.2, seeing local variables just fine. If you do a debug with the following setup 'Powershell: Interactive Session' and call on the script in that session is it the same result?

Comment: Yeah, I can fine too it. I think it might be that script I don't know if there's an encoding issue or what it's really random. When I run it seems to screw up the debugger. If I run it with no breakpoints it works (although I'm not running the whole thing yet just a couple of the functions). I've noticed if I don't run it at all I can debug other scripts. If I do run it then I get the same behaviour in other scripts. Quite Random. I'm going to pick it apart bit by bit and see if I can find the offending code. It's about 800 lines long so could take a bit.

Comment: I did finally find some sort of a solution to this not sure why it worked though. Basically deleted the local repo, i.e. moved to recycle bin not just removed and downloaded it again. Could have something to do with VSCodes Trust functionality.